# How to get the located drive of a folder?

Tags: java

I have a folder named myFolder.  This folder is in D:\project\myFolder.  I want to get the driver is located in this folder.

In other words, I have a folder named "myfolder."  The path of this folder is D:\project.  I would to store D:\ in a string

For example just get D:\  .
If change the folder location (E:\projet\myFolder) now I only get E:\
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Excuse me, did You try own solution / code? Can You post something? Suppose I don't understand, what's problem

Comment: I have a folder named myfolder the path of this folder is d:\project

Comment: I have a folder named my folder.the path of this folder is d:\project\myFolder Now I want to access the driver just for example my program returns d:\

Comment: "You have". How do you have? Show the code you have so far. You have it in a `String`? In a `File`? In a `Path`? As an abstract thought in your head?

Comment: I want to store d:\ in a string .If you want i can mail my source code to you

Comment: Or how about you edit the question and insert a *minimal* example for all to read. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: moving responses from comments to the original post

Comment: Must be a training class going on right now. Seems to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286626/getting-drive-name-that-java-class-running-on-that-drive#32286747

Answer (score 0):

you can create a temporary file and get its location look how to do that here :

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-filepath-of-a-file-in-java/

after that you can do loop to go down in direction until you will be at first folder . / or to take with string function the first three char of the text.

Comment: That is a really bad example. You should use `File.getParentFile()` or `File.getParent()` instead of string manipulation. Or `Path.getParent()` if using newer API.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String driveName = new File("temp").getAbsolutePath.substring(0,3);
```