# Getting Drive name that java class running on that drive

Tags: java

How i can get Drive name that java class running on that drive?

I need only drive name not whole path.

For example my file running in `D:\folder1\Main.java` and i need this: `D:\`

Comment: Wouldn't find the first occurence of ":" work? Not very portable anyway

Comment: You can't run file `Main.java`. You can compile it into `Main.class`, which may be located in a different folder. It may then be packaged in a .jar file, stored in a 3rd folder. When executed, the "current directory" may be a 4th folder. Those 4 folders may be on 4 different drives, so which drive are you after? --- Complications: If not on Windows, there is no drive. If running from network share, there is no drive.

Comment: Must be a training class going on right now. Seems to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286483/how-to-get-the-located-drive-of-a-folder#32286483

Answer (score 1):

Use `Path.getRoot()`, which on Windows is the drive.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the complete path for your java program:

```
  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
```